# Smart refactoring using Roslyn CTP

Tags: c#, .net, refactoring, roslyn

I'm running some analysis tools on our build like StyleCop/FXCop.

What i'd like to achieve is auto-correct some of the warnings produced by these.

Do you think this can be done using the Roslyn CTP? is there any other tool that allows:

1. Scanning my code text for some rule not being followed.
2. Replacing this with the correct code.

Some of the operations can be done using a simple text replace of the VS editor, but more complicated things require use of some other tool.

So my question is - to this end, is the Roslyn CTP the tool to use? or what other tools exist for .NET for doing this?

Comment: In principle Roslyn should be able to such changes. The CTP is still pretty rough though, so I'm not sure how well it will work for now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is certainly one of the scenarios that Roslyn addresses. Take a look at [this walkthrough](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh543922) that demonstrates how to write a "Quick Fix" using Roslyn. In fact, the CTP also ships with a couple of samples that demonstrate how one could write stylecop / fxcop style rules using Roslyn.

You can also glance through [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh500769) for an overview of the overall scope of the CTP.

Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft on the Roslyn team.

Answer (score 4):

OP asks, "what other tools exist for .NET for doing this?"

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) is a [source-to-source program transformation tool](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html).

DMS can parse, analyze, and transform source codes for [many computer languages](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds) such as C++, Java, COBOL, and particularly including [C#](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/FrontEnds/CSharpFrontEnd.html).  It can also handle multiple languages simultaneously.